# Why do my `for` commands run in `cmd` but not within a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have below `cmd` commands, when I run these in a batch file it doesn't execute as the command prompt terminates. But when I run these one by one manually it executes.

```
CD /d o:\database\UK
dir *LWRKF03* *NCOM* *DTP* *LLIQ01* *LCOG01* *LCIMS02* *LCLS01* *LOLYM* *LCHUB01* *ISD* *PUKODYS01* *PUKHSSS02* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%">C:\Users\43874210\Desktop\UK\FoundFiles.TXT
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LWRKF03* *NCOM* *DTP* *LLIQ01* *LCOG01* *LCIMS02* *LCLS01* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" C:\Users\43874210\Desktop\UK
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LWRKF03* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" X:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *NCOM* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" W:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *DTP* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" T:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LLIQ01* *LCOG01* *PUKODYS01* *PUKHSSS02* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" Q:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LCIMS02* *LCLS01* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" S:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LOLYM* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" R:
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in ('"dir *LCHUB01* *ISD* /s /t:c | findstr "%date%""') do copy "%i" H:
```

Comment: within batchfiles, you have to use `%%i` instead of `%i` (described in `for /?`)

Comment: @Stephan you should turn this into answer.

Comment: @Christian.K done. Had to check some other quirks first.

Comment: You say command prompt terminates, so I guess you are running the batch file by double-clicking; you should open a new command prompt (`cmd`) window and run the batch file by typing its path into it (enclosed in `""`), so you could see any error messages...

Answer (score 3):

within batchfiles, you have to use %%i instead of %i (described in for /?)

example line:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%i in ('dir *LWRKF03* *NCOM* *DTP* *LLIQ01* *LCOG01* *LCIMS02* *LCLS01* /a-d /s /t:c ^| findstr "%date%"') do copy "%%i" C:\Users\43874210\Desktop\UK
```

(I also corrected the syntax of `in (....)` and added `dir` parameter `/a-d` to exclude directories)

By the way - for me it's `Tokens=4`